# C: accessing members of struct in a function

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to use the struct member 'size' in my function print_shoe, but my for loop doesn't run. However, if I replace 'c->size' with an int in the for loop, it runs just fine

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DECK_SIZE 52
#define NUM_FACES 13
#define NUM_SUITS 4
#define LENGTH_FACES 6
#define LENGTH_SUITS 9

typedef struct cards {
  char suits[NUM_SUITS][LENGTH_SUITS];
  char faces[NUM_FACES][NUM_FACES];
  int suit, face, card, value, size;
  int *values[NUM_FACES];
} cards;

char buf[101];
void print_shoe();
void init_decks();
int rand_int();
void shuffle();

int main(void) {

  srand( time(NULL) );

  int decks_input = 0;    
  int numberOfDecks = 1;

  do {
    printf("\nEnter number of decks to be used in the game (1-8):\n\n");
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL)
      if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &decks_input))
        numberOfDecks = decks_input;
     } while (numberOfDecks < 1 || numberOfDecks > 8);

  cards *shoe = malloc(sizeof(cards) * numberOfDecks * DECK_SIZE);
  shoe->size = numberOfDecks * DECK_SIZE;

  shuffle(shoe);
  print_shoe(shoe);

  free(shoe);

  return 0;
}

void print_shoe(cards *c) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < c->size; i++) {
    printf("card #%d = %s of %s\n", i+1, c->faces[c[i].face], c->suits[c[i].suit]);
  }
}

void init_decks(cards *c) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < c->size; i++) {
    c[i].card = i;
    c[i].suit = c[i].card % NUM_SUITS;
    c[i].face = c[i].card % NUM_FACES;
  }  
}

void shuffle(cards *c) {
  init_decks(c);

  int i, j;
  cards tmp;
  for (i = c->size - 1; i > 0 ; i--) {
    j = rand_int(i + 1);
    tmp = c[j];
    c[j] = c[i];
    c[i] = tmp;
  }
}

int rand_int(int n) {
  int limit = RAND_MAX - RAND_MAX % n;
  int rnd;

  do {
    rnd = rand();
     } while (rnd >= limit);
  return rnd % n;
}
```

Edit: Question has been updated extensively in response to comments that it needed more clarification

Comment: Your code does not compile. 1. put `print_shoe` before `main` 2. `(cards *)malloc(...)`.  After I change these, it runs good on my machine.

Comment: @gongzhitaao: The cast is unnecessary and a bad idea. Just be sure yuou have `#include <stdlib.h>`, and the conversion from `void*` to `cards*` will be done implicitly.

Comment: You haven't defined `buf` or `DECK_SIZE`, and you're missing the required `#include` directives for `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>`. And you say your function "can't access" the struct members. What does that mean? What happens when you try? Do you get a compile-time error messages? If so, show it to us. Show us a [complete sample program](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem, and tell us what the problem is.

Comment: I see I left out some important parts there - updating question now

Comment: In addition to what Keith said, it's not clear why you are allocating so much memory for cards. Why even make it a data structure if it only contains one element?

Comment: I was just trying to simplify, updated with more details now

Comment: well your model struct is icky... you need to model a card, and model a deck... and model a shoe... you have it all kind of muddled... deck and shoe can be just an array of cards, but just model them as they exist

Comment: I thought I was pretty much on the right track.. when you mention deck as an array of cards, you still want it to be a member of the struct?

Comment: `printf("card #%d = %s of %s\n", i+1, c->faces[c[i].face], c->suits[c[i].suit]);` you refer to the part that has not been initialized.

Comment: because shuffle() was not called? problem is still the same

Comment: A debugger would have shown this pretty readily: You initialized the `size` of the first `cards` in the array pointed to by `shoe`, and the other `cards` have uninitialized values for `size`. When you shuffle, one of the uninitialized `cards` becomes the first entry in the `shoe`, and you are using an uninitialized variable. The `size` does not belong in the `cards` structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the revised code, you have:

```
cards *shoe = malloc(sizeof(cards) * numberOfDecks * DECK_SIZE);
shoe->size = numberOfDecks * DECK_SIZE;

// You probably need init_decks(shoe); here!!!

shuffle(shoe);
print_shoe(shoe);
```

Your code in `print_shoe()` is simply printing, but you've not initialized the data from `malloc()` other than the size, so you're printing garbage.  The data returned by `malloc()` is uninitialized and must be initialized before it is read.  The question changed while I was typing; you still haven't called `init_decks(shoe);` as you need to.

---

This is not why it isn't working — I'm not sure what the problem is now — but it is almost worth commenting on.  You have:

```
void shuffle(cards *c) {
  init_decks(c);

  int i, j;
  cards tmp;
  for (i = c->size - 1; i > 0 ; i--) {
    j = rand_int(i + 1);
    tmp = c[j];
    c[j] = c[i];
    c[i] = tmp;
  }
}
```

If you're going to use the C99 technique of declaring variables with minimal scope, then you should be writing:

```
void shuffle(cards *c) {
  init_decks(c);
  for (int i = c->size - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    int j = rand_int(i + 1);
    cards tmp = c[j];
    c[j] = c[i];
    c[i] = tmp;
  }
}
```

(I wouldn't have missed the call to `init_decks()` had it been written like that.)

---

As noted in a comment, your `cards` structure is rather top-heavy.  You allocate (for each card) enough space to store the ranks and suits that it could possibly have.  This is really not necessary.

This code separates a `Deck` from a `Card`.  It uses a flexible array member in the `Deck` structure to hold the cards, which is convenient.  You may prefer to use a regular pointer there, in which case you'll need a pair of memory allocations and a function `deck_free()` to release the memory allocated by `deck_alloc()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_FACES 13
#define NUM_SUITS 4
#define DECK_SIZE (NUM_FACES * NUM_SUITS)
#define LENGTH_FACES 6
#define LENGTH_SUITS 9

static const char suits[NUM_SUITS][LENGTH_SUITS] =
{
    "Clubs",
    "Diamonds",
    "Hearts",
    "Spades"
};
static const char faces[NUM_FACES][NUM_FACES] =
{
    "Ace",
    "Deuce",
    "Three",
    "Four",
    "Five",
    "Six",
    "Seven",
    "Eight",
    "Nine",
    "Ten",
    "Jack",
    "Queen",
    "King",
};

typedef struct Card
{
  int suit;
  int face;
  int card;
} Card;

typedef struct Deck
{
  int size;
  Card cards[];     // Flexible array member
} Deck;

void print_shoe(const Deck *d);
void init_decks(Deck *d);
int rand_int(int n);
void shuffle(Deck *d);
static Deck *deck_alloc(int numberOfDecks);

int main(void)
{
    srand( time(NULL) );
    int numberOfDecks = 1;

    do
    {
        char buf[101];
        printf("\nEnter number of decks to be used in the game (1-8):\n\n");
        if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL)
        {
            int decks_input;    
            if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &decks_input))
                numberOfDecks = decks_input;
        }
    } while (numberOfDecks < 1 || numberOfDecks > 8);

    Deck *shoe = deck_alloc(numberOfDecks);
    shuffle(shoe);
    print_shoe(shoe);
    free(shoe);

    return 0;
}

static Deck *deck_alloc(int numberOfDecks)
{
    Deck *shoe  = malloc(sizeof(Deck) + (sizeof(Card) * numberOfDecks * DECK_SIZE));
    if (shoe == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    shoe->size = numberOfDecks * DECK_SIZE;
    return shoe;
}

void print_shoe(const Deck *d)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < d->size; i++)
        printf("card #%d = %s of %s\n", i+1, faces[d->cards[i].face], suits[d->cards[i].suit]);
}

void init_decks(Deck *d)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < d->size; i++)
    {
        d->cards[i].card = i;
        d->cards[i].suit = d->cards[i].card % NUM_SUITS;
        d->cards[i].face = d->cards[i].card % NUM_FACES;
    }  
}

void shuffle(Deck *d)
{
    init_decks(d);
    for (int i = d->size - 1; i > 0 ; i--)
    {
        int j = rand_int(i + 1);
        Card tmp = d->cards[j];
        d->cards[j] = d->cards[i];
        d->cards[i] = tmp;
    }
}

int rand_int(int n)
{
    int limit = RAND_MAX - RAND_MAX % n;
    int rnd;

    do
    {
        rnd = rand();
    } while (rnd >= limit);
    return rnd % n;
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./cards

Enter number of decks to be used in the game (1-8):

1
card #1 = Eight of Clubs
card #2 = Jack of Clubs
card #3 = Deuce of Diamonds
card #4 = Jack of Hearts
card #5 = Queen of Clubs
card #6 = Four of Hearts
card #7 = Six of Spades
card #8 = King of Hearts
card #9 = Five of Spades
card #10 = King of Clubs
card #11 = Deuce of Clubs
card #12 = King of Spades
card #13 = Four of Spades
card #14 = Nine of Diamonds
card #15 = Five of Hearts
card #16 = Deuce of Spades
card #17 = Ten of Clubs
card #18 = Five of Diamonds
card #19 = Ten of Spades
card #20 = Three of Spades
card #21 = Nine of Hearts
card #22 = Six of Clubs
card #23 = Ace of Clubs
card #24 = Three of Clubs
card #25 = Queen of Hearts
card #26 = Jack of Diamonds
card #27 = Nine of Clubs
card #28 = Four of Clubs
card #29 = Seven of Spades
card #30 = Ace of Diamonds
card #31 = Six of Diamonds
card #32 = Three of Hearts
card #33 = Queen of Diamonds
card #34 = Ten of Hearts
card #35 = Ten of Diamonds
card #36 = Seven of Diamonds
card #37 = Seven of Clubs
card #38 = Deuce of Hearts
card #39 = Ace of Hearts
card #40 = Jack of Spades
card #41 = Eight of Diamonds
card #42 = Eight of Spades
card #43 = Ace of Spades
card #44 = Three of Diamonds
card #45 = Queen of Spades
card #46 = Five of Clubs
card #47 = Four of Diamonds
card #48 = King of Diamonds
card #49 = Nine of Spades
card #50 = Eight of Hearts
card #51 = Six of Hearts
card #52 = Seven of Hearts
$
```

Comment: init_decks(shoe) gets called inside shuffle (even though that might be bad practice). I apologize for the editing, tried doing it asap - I really don't want to waste anyone's time

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by initializing data returned by `malloc()`

Comment: I missed the call to `init_decks()` in `shuffle()`, and when I started to answer, there wasn't a call to `shuffle()` either.  Initializing the data means that before you try reading anything from the space returned by `malloc()`, you write something to it.  There's no guarantee that you'll get zeros or any other value in the allocated space; it will generally be a quasi-random mishmash of bytes (but it would not be a good source of entropy for random processes).

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: Your `init_decks()` does some initialization &mdash; it writes to some elements of the `cards` structure (and fortunately, `NUM_DECKS == NUM_FACES * NUM_SUITS`). However, your `cards` structure is a mixture of several descriptions. You've got enough storage space for a full deck of card names in each entry, but you only have one `face` and one `card` and one `suit`. You need to clean up the structure. You also need to set everything. The standard way of initializing allocated memory is with `memset()` (usually specifying 0 as the byte value) or by using `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`.

Comment: do I need to do this just once for the struct, or for every of its elements?

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the question directly and ignoring the wisdom of this approach, your problem is as follows(as also mentioned by Raymond Chen).

```
  cards *shoe = malloc(sizeof(cards) * numberOfDecks * DECK_SIZE);
```

The line above makes shoe point to enough memory to store `(numberOfDecks * DECK_SIZE)` `struct cards`.  The structs, and thus there members, are all unitialized at this point meaning `shoe[i].size` could be any sequence of bits.

shoe->size = numberOfDecks * DECK_SIZE;

This line looks at the *only the first* `struct cards` and sets its `size` to `(numberOfDecks * DECK_SIZE)`.  The rest of the `struct cards`'s `size` members remain unititialized.

In `shuffle`, your call to `init_decks` initializes `card`, `suit`, and `face` but not `size`.  When you later shuffle the cards, a card with an unititialized `size` member has a good chance of becoming first.

Thus, under your current approach, the following should get what you want if you add this line to `init_decks`.

```
void init_decks(cards *c) {
      int i;
      int size = c->size;
      for (i = 0; i < c->size; i++) {
            c[i].size = size;
            c[i].card = i;
            c[i].suit = c[i].card % NUM_SUITS;
            c[i].face = c[i].card % NUM_FACES;
       }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a pointer but haven't initialized it a valid memory location to point to.

```
 ex *ex_p = malloc(sizeof(ex));
 ex_p->size = 10;
```

Comment: I did do that in my code, unfortunately.. Can you spot anything else? It's as if loop doesn't even run.. But doesn't give me any errors either. If I simply swap 'ptr->size' in my for loop with the value '10', it works out fine

Comment: If you have just once instance, there is no point of iterating or using a for loop. Can you please post your complete actual code ?